# sed substitution with an "or" condition doesn't appear to work

Tags: bash, sed, sh

My sed regex "or" doesn't appear to work when an insert/substitution is involved.  Given the following data file, if a keyword exists after the fifth field, I want to insert a carriage return before keyword. The idea then is to print the individual lines.  I understand that Python, Perl, etc. would be better, but Bourne shell is the requirement.

data.txt:

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 first('echo hello') second('ls /tmp')
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 second('ls -la /home') forth('ls /tmp')
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 first ('touch /tmp/hello')
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 fifth('echo hello world') first('ls /etc') third ('mkdir -p /tmp/blah')
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
    oldifs="$IFS"

    scriptlets=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 6- | sed -e "s=\(first|second|third|forth|fifth\)=\'$'\n\1=g")
    IFS=$'\n' # this works for Bourne shell 3.2.57
    for scriptlet in $scriptlets; do
        echo "-> $scriptlet"
    done
    IFS="$oldifs"
    echo ""

done < ./data.txt
```

The desired output:

```
-> first('echo hello') 
-> second('ls /tmp')

-> second('ls -la /home') 
-> forth('ls /tmp')

-> first ('touch /tmp/hello')

-> fifth('echo hello world')
-> first('ls /etc')
-> third ('mkdir -p /tmp/blah')
```

Comment: `bash` is not the Bourne shell, which virtually no one uses any more.

Comment: bash: "bourne again shell". I guess it's easy to mix those up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't combine the sed "or" and substitution/insert together.  Hence, I needed to break the sed statement into individual statements.

```
scriptlets=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 6- | sed -e 's/ first/\'$'\nfirst/' -e 's/second/\'$'\nsecond/' -e 's/ third/\'$'\nthird/' -e 's/forth/\'$'\nforth/' -e 's/ fifth/\'$'\nfifth/')
```

Answer (score 1):

In sed under `-E`, the grouping parentheses should not be backslashed. Backslashed parenthesis matches the literal one.

Moreover, your assignment to `$scriptlets` is missing a closing parenthesis for the command substitution. Also, are you sure you want to use the command substitution twice, once in the assignment and once in the `for` loop?

Finally, you probably meant `while read line` instead of `for read line` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

*This started as a comment but got too long. See [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413829/4518341) for a proper solution.*

There are a bunch of things wrong here.

1. `for read line` is invalid; you probably meant `while read line`.
2. `scriptlets=$(...` is missing a closing paren.
3. `$(scriptlets)` is probably not what you want - you probably meant `${scriptlets}`
4. `echo $line` is questionable. You probably want to quote that variable
5. Bash is not the same as the Bourne shell, though it it compatible. For example the Bourne shell doesn't support C-style strings, `$'...'`, as in `IFS=$'\n'`.
6. `\n` is a newline character, while `\r` is a carriage return. (This is more of a nitpick, but it might confuse people reading the question.)

Try using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to debug.

Answer (score 0):

By default, sed uses "basic" regular expression syntax, which doesn't support alternation (the "or" you're talking about). To use alternation, use `sed -E` and "extended" regex syntax. Also, your syntax for inserting a newline into the replacement pattern is garbled. Try this instead:

```
nl=$'\n'
... | sed -E $'s=(first|second|third|forth|fifth)=\\\n\\1=g' )
```

But actually, I'd recommend doing the surrounding code differently as well. It currently reads lined from the file one by one, passes them through `cut` and `sed` one, collects the output, then uses `for` to split it into even more lines. Why not just pass the entire file through `cut` and `sed` at once, and then split the output from that? Also, it's generally better to use a `while read` loop to loop over lines (because it doesn't do silly things with shell wildcards). How about this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cut -d ' ' -f 6- data.txt | \
    sed -E $'s=(first|second|third|forth|fifth)=\\\n\\1=g' | \
    while read scriptlet; do
        echo "-> $scriptlet"
    done
echo
```

Note that this has the consequence that the loop runs in a subshell (because it's in a pipeline). If that's a problem, you need bash (not plain sh) and its process substitution feature:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read scriptlet; do
    echo "-> $scriptlet"
done < <(cut -d ' ' -f 6- data.txt | \
         sed -E $'s=(first|second|third|forth|fifth)=\\\n\\1=g' )
echo
```